# Returning a Value in Void Objective C Fn Prevents RN Build

Tags: objective-c, react-native

Although I'm not an objective C programmer, I need to bridge a really simple objective C function into my react native app. I would like to get a list of photo album titles in objective C and send them to the javascript part of the app.

At build time, I got a error informing me that the following function should not return a value, since its void.

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getAlbumTitles)
{
  PHFetchResult *albums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:nil];
  return albums; 
}
```

But I do not wish to pass any parameters to this particular method, I just want the results of the native function. So, how do I get the result of albums to javascript?

Comment: I don't know react, but if we wanted that to compile in objective c, we'd declare it `- (PHFetchResult *)getAlbumTitles { // ... }`

Comment: i just tried that and got an "Expected selector for obj-c method" error

Comment: Compiler error or execution?

Comment: Compiler error, I just plugged in your suggestion above, because I'm pretty naive in obj c

Comment: Hmm.  Sorry I can't help.  Only to say that, if PHFetchResult is a defined class, the little snippet definitely compiles in objective-c.  That's confirmed by inspection and actually running through the compiler just now

Comment: I think it should be a class, since I pulled it straight from the ios docs and imported the requisite stuff. Either way, I found a solution, turns out I need to pass a callback to the function and get the data in js through that, which is weird. Either way, thanks for your prompt responses!